# In vb.net when you break out of a loop, do you break all the nested loops?

Tags: vb.net, loops

So I have some vb.net code, and I have a nested For loop inside a For loop, and then I have EXIT FOR statement, will it break out of one loop, or the whole chain?

Comment: This is a very easy thing to test for yourself

Comment: Well, you *could* test by making a simple vb.net app and trying it out there.

Comment: I can't believe 5 of you are discussing this and noone mentions the manual. Thank heaven for Neil's answer

Comment: HOW DARE YOU ASK THIS?!??!?!  ;))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`Exit For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2at9t47%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will only exit the current `For` loop that it is executing in.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2at9t47%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> **Exit For**
>
> Immediately exits the For loop in which it appears. Execution
> continues with the statement following the Next statement. Exit For
> can be used only inside a For...Next or For Each...Next loop. When
> used within nested For loops, Exit For exits the innermost loop and
> transfers control to the next higher level of nesting.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question:- It will break out of One loop.

Definition:

**Exit For**:

> *"Immediately exits the For loop **in which it appears**. Execution continues with the statement following the Next statement ... Exit For
>   exits the **innermost loop** and transfers control to **the next
>   higher level of nesting**."*

Have a look at [MSDN for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2at9t47%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @peter its a helpful resource called "documentation". It's the first place to look when you have basic questions about a language feature.